# User to view/change own membership as well as address details etc

Tags: civimember, profile

I want users to be able to login and see/change their address etc as well as at least see their membership type (one of four available) and preferably change the membership. I got the login sorted, I got the profile I want but when one meets the other this message: "Profile search, view and edit are not supported for Profiles which include fields for more than one record type."

How do I get around this? Or is it not possible for members to see/edit their membership type on CiviCRM?

On Wordpress btw.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a profile with all the information you want the user to edit. (I would not let a user change membership type, but as you wish.)
2. Create a new page on Wordpress - call it View Profile - or whatever you want.  Then embed the CiviCRM shortcode by clicking the insert civicrm content button, choose profile, choose the profile, choose view, and don't over ride.
3. Create a new page on Wordpress - call it Edit Profile - or whatever you want.  Then embed the CiviCRM shortcode by clicking the insert civicrm content button, choose profile, choose the profile, choose edit, and don't over ride.
4. Create links to those pages for users to access.

Optionally use the members plugin and restrict the content of those pages to only members or whatever configuration you want.

Comment: I will try that thanks. 

"(I would not let a user change membership type, but as you wish.)"  -- its a fair point and will probably

Comment: Thanks - if this was helpful, please choose as answer and up vote me :)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative for letting users see their membership info (and contributions etc) is to give them access to their own Contact Dashboard. You can specify what should show on the Dashboard, eg Groups, Related Contacts as well